# C - Trying to determine number of elements in buffer filled by getline()

Tags: c, getline, strtok

I have seen a lot of places saying that `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])` should work in determining the size of the array, but this does not work for me

```
char* buf = NULL;
size_t len;
len = 0;
while(getline(&buf,&len,stdin) >= 0 ){
    unsigned int i;
    size_t size= sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        char* s;
        int pos;
        s = strtok(buf, " ");
        unsigned int j;
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++){
            doStuff();
        }
```

I want to deterine how many Strings are in `buf` so that I know how many times `strtok()` needs to be called in order to do something with each letter of the word.

Comment: The thing is, `buf` is a pointer, not an array. `sizeof(buf)` is just the size of a pointer.

Comment: The number of characters in `buf` has nothing to do with the number of times `strtok` will be called (which is the number of words). I suggest you look up some examples of using `strtok` properly, as the way you're using it will just return the first word multiple times.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])` only works for arrays, not pointer, `sizeof` will be evaluated on compile time, because the size is already known by the compiler. that is not the case with pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline()` returns the **number of characters read**. Use the return if you need the number of characters read. If you need the number of tokens parsed by `strtok`, keep an `index` and increment it.

```
len = 0;
ssize_t n = 0;    /* number of chars read by getline   */
size_t index = 0; /* number of tokens parsed by strtok */

while ((n = getline (&buf, &len, stdin)) >= 0 ) {
    ...
    char *s = buf;
    for (s = strtok (s, " "); s; s = strtok (NULL, " ")) {
        index++;
        ...
    }
    ...
    for (j = 0; j < index; j++){
        doStuff();
    }
```

**Note:** `buf` is *not* preserved by `strtok` (it will have `null-terminating` characters embedded in it by `strtok`). If you need `buf` later, make a copy before calling `strtok`.

Answer (score 1):

check the return value of getline()

from man-page

```
RETURN VALUE         top

   On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of characters
   read, including the delimiter character, but not including the
   terminating null byte ('\0').  This value can be used to handle
   embedded null bytes in the line read.

   Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-
   file condition).  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate
   the cause.
```